# How to implement a promise.each inside a then of outer promise in Bluebird

Tags: promise, bluebird

I have structure like the following

```
functionA()
.then(() => {
    return Promise.mapSeries(array1, function(()=>{
        return functionC()
        .then(()=>{

        })
        then(()=>{
            // expected value printed here for each item item1 and item2 of array1 
        })
    })
})
.then(() => {
    // Part B - Complete for all array elements
    // But unexpected result - array1 second item overlapped with array1 first item
})
```

In PartB I expect the combination of values for 1st and 2nd items in array1, but instead unexpected combination comes, where item2 result overlaps item1 result. Where has the code gone wrong?

Comment: Why don't you run partB inside then of promise.each?

Comment: @osmanraifgunes inside each, those then are for each array entry, and partB is for the final result combining all results of each.

Comment: @bergi Can you have a look at this?

Comment: @benjamin-gruenbaum is the approach wrong?